# install a web site to IIS without creating a virtual directory

Tags: iis, installation

How to install a web site to IIS7/IIS6 without creating a virtual directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use Microsoft.Web.Administration for creating web sites in IIS7.

Answer (score 0):

Just dump it in C:\inetpub\wwwroot

Comment: How do I do that in my web setup project? You have to chose web site and virtual directory there.

Comment: you said without creating a virtual directory!! If you want you can have the wizard create the website for you http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323972